# I can't see my hard disk in CentOs. How can I solve this?

Tags: centos, hard-disk

I have the main disk with Windows 7, and I installed CentOS in a flash USB. I want to delete data of main hard disk using CentOS Gnu/Linux, so I can use it to store backups. I want to do something like an NAS server.

My problem is that I can't see the main hard disk in Linux. I don't know how to solve this. I tried with many commands, although it's not work.

Thanks guys !

Comment: You probably shutdown Windows with the Windows "Fast Boot" option enabled. This left the hard disk in a weird state that is good for faster booting Windows, but nothing else. Boot back into Windows, clear "Fast Boot", shutdown Windows and try again.

Comment: please post `fdisk -l` output

Comment: @waltinator I wil try this, thanks !

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I show this with your command: I show the disk of installation CentOs /dev/sda: 29,3 GiB, but I can't show the hard disk with Windows

Comment: You should see your BIOS/UEFI settings for your drives, if it is in RAID mode, Linux won't see your drives, you can see my answer here, if that is the case: https://superuser.com/a/1359471/402107

Comment: Edit question to tell us what you tried, and show us what happened.